# Active Record has many through, create and delete symmetry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Users have many Groups through Memberships. Groups have many Users through Memberships. Joining a group is essentially creating a Membership between the two models. Being kicked from a group is removing that Membership.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :memberships

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :groups, through: :memberships

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Of course, if a Group or User is destroyed, their corresponding Memberships should be destroyed. I'm having trouble writing the "join" and "kick" methods where the Memberships are created and destroyed.

*models/group.rb*

```
def self.join(user, group)
    group.memberships.create(user: user)
end

def self.kick(user, group)
    group.memberships.where(user: user).first.destroy!
end
```

When I run `Group.join` I get:

```
2.4.0 :043 > g.memberships
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Membership id: 3, group_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-01-07 19:32:47", updated_at: "2017-01-07 19:32:47", is_admin: nil>]> 
2.4.0 :044 > u.memberships
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

So the membership belongs to the group but not to the user?

I get the same exact output when I run `Group.kick`

EDIT:

@Iceman's answer is correct. However, I was testing the method in the Rails console. Whenever a database object for example `u = User.find(1)` is transformed, the `u` is the same one it was before it transformed. You must use `u.reload` in order to see the changes. In other words, his answer works perfectly fine, but I was testing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to do it like this I feel

```
def self.join(user, group)
  user.groups << group
end
```

The `<<` is used to add an item to an array

```
def self.kick(user, group)
  Membership.where(user_id: user.id, group_id: group.id).delete_all
end
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on your answer? I've only seen the `<<` used for inheritance

Comment: @Carpetfizz Certainly, `<<` is used to add an item to an array, it's just a nice syntactic sugar. You might just as well do `user.groups += group`

Comment: Thanks for the update. The `join` function you proposed seems to work. I'm confused as to how the `user` is added to the `group` without explicitly stating. Also, the kick method didn't work (`u.groups` and `g.users`) still shows the corresponding User and Group

Comment: It is done by adding another group to his group array, and it's updated automatically in the db.

Comment: `kick` should work, it deletes the relationship between the `group` and the `user`

Comment: You can try `delete!` or `destroy!` to see if it throws an error.

Comment: yes, I can see how the group is added to the user, but I can't see how user is added to group. Regarding kick, yes the Membership is deleted but `u.groups` and `g.users` still shows Groups and Users respectively

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132588/discussion-between-iceman-and-carpetfizz).

Comment: please see my edit, your answer works fine, I was testing it wrong :)

Comment: @Carpetfizz Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

I like the accepted answer, but I don't think these methods belong in the Membership model, and should really be moved to the User model.

I would also switch from Class methods to instance methods, like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def join(group)
    groups << group
  end

  def kick_from(group)
    memberships.where(group: group).delete_all
  end
```

Now you can join and kick like so:

```
group = Group.find(params[:id])
current_user.join group
current_user.kick_from group
```

Hope this helps. It all depends on where your methods live.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. These methods were actually in the Group model but I think it makes more sense to add them as instance methods in the User model like you suggested.